# PHPExcel reader type for Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to open an excel file using phpexcel.

When I open it in microsoft excel it is detected as Excel 97-2003 Worksheet.

However, opening it by phpexcel gives an error.
I tried reader types Excel5, Excel2007, Excel2003XML
all fail to open.
Is there another reader type to use here?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of variants such as xlsb files that aren't supported: what does the IOFactory `identify()` method tell you the file is? And explain what you mean by "fails to open". Does it give an error/exception? Does it write anything to log files? Does it run out of memory?

Comment: @MarkBaker detects it as html which is not correct. thanks.

Comment: If identify() believes that it has detected an HTML file, then it has recognised that at least some of the content looks like markup.... try opening the file in a text editor to see what it contains